# Dynamic Entity Navigation Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity called Asset, similar to below:

```
public class Asset
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public int AddedById { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeAdded { get; set; }

    public virtual AssetType Type { get; set; }
    public virtual ITUser AddedBy { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to have a navigation property that is linked to a single table, but that table is dependent on what type of Asset it is. For instance, if the Asset is of the type "Printer" then I want the navigation property to link to the PrinterDetail entity. My initial way of going about this was to have unused columns in the Asset entity, but I figured that was wasteful or bad practice. Is there something that I am overlooking or is this just something that cannot be done?

Thanks for any advice given.

Answer (score 0):

if you want  navigate printerDetail by type you can use entityfraemwork inheritance strategy:

Table per Hierarchy (TPH)
Table per Type (TPT)
Table per Concrete class (TPC)

you have to create Model per each type and use TPT strategy for that.
and then you can use fluent api for config mapping for that.
parent Model (Asset) must define as abstract class and AssesTypes Must be Drive from the Parent.

[more information](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)